# What are the options for getting around a memory shortage when running a large batch of inserts?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a large batch of insert statements (about 30 megs) generated to resynchronize one database to match another. I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 64-bit on a Win 7 machine with 8 gigs of memory.

When I run the query in SSMS, I get "Query executed with errors" and no output message. After some fiddling around and trying to run it outside of SSMS, I realized that it is an out-of-memory error. In fact, even after it errors out, I find that the SQL Server service is using about 5.5 gigs of memory!

Is there a parameter I can adjust that will allow SQL to run this? The alternative is to write a program that breaks the query into batches and runs them. Interestingly, this seems to only occur with large queries that contain inserts. Large queries that contain updates seem to work fine. Perhaps this is due to the way they are written to the transaction log. The query is output as a series of many inserts, however, and this can't be changed.

Anyway, is there a setting in SQL Server I can adjust to fix this? I would appreciate any advice anyone can give.

Edit: Thanks for your reply, bluefooted. My colleague and I had the same impression when we first saw the messageless error--it looked like SSMS was running out of memory. However, on further inspection, it looks like it might be SQL Server. Let me explain. We are using Red Gate's SQL Comparison SDK with Visual Studio to generate diff queries and then conditionally running certain statements to bring 2 databases into convergence according to certain rules. Thus, after encountering this problem, we used the included Executor object to run the script. We received the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  Message=There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=17
  LineNumber=79180
  Number=701
  Procedure=""
  Server=QA1
  State=123
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at RedGate.Shared.SQL.ExecutionBlock.BlockExecutor.ExecuteBlock(ExecutionBlock block, String server, String database, Boolean integratedSecurity, String userName, String password)
       at IO.Practiceware.DbSync.Csharp.Program.RunScript(String path, String server, String database)
  InnerException:
```

I don't know what can be made of this, but my more knowledgeable colleague said it basically means the SQL Server itself is running out of memory. I'd appreciate any insights you have into this.

Comment: What's the out of memory error that you're getting?  Usually when I have a problem like that it's SSMS that is running out of memory, not SQL Server.  When you say you ran it "outside of SSMS" how did you run it?

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

Try breaking the inserts up into batches. Every 1000 lines or so insert something like:

```
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
INSERT ...

GO

INSERT ...
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
```

Might also not hurt to issue `CHECKPOINT` occasionally to reduce the impact on the log.

Instead of sending thousands of individual insert statements, try combining them. You can do this in multiple ways, a couple of examples:

```
INSERT dbo.table(col1,col2) SELECT 1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2;

-- or    

INSERT dbo.table(col1,col2)
VALUES(1,2),(2,2),(3,2);
```

Additionally you could store the data (rather than the insert commmands) in a flat text file and use `BULK INSERT`, `bcp` etc. instead of regular inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a feeling we will end up dividing up the commands into batches.